# Confusion about DI, IoC and service locators

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, service-locator

I have read various articles about IoC, DIP, DI and Service Locators but I'm a bit confused which is which because some articles have too vague examples and some other articles have just some specific examples without mentioning other cases.

**Could you please clear this up for me, looking at the examples below and shortly explaining which examples match which pattern?**

- manually passing interface to constructor:

  ```
  class Consumer
  {
    public Consumer(IStore store){...}
  }
  ...

  Consumer c = new Consumer(new ConcreteStore());
  ```
- the same as the first example but using some 3rd party library (Unity, Windsor, Ninject)
- the same as the first example but using BaseStore class instead of IStore interface
- passing dependency to some other method, not to constructor:

  ```
  class Consumer
  {
    public BySomething(IStore store){...}
  }
  ...

  Consumer c = new Consumer();
  c.BySomething(new ConcreteStore());
  ```
- passing dependencies masked inside of some other interface (bonus for this solution - when some other things are invented in the "world" and Consumer wishes to use them, we don't have to change constructor argument but just update IWorld; and we can completely replace entire World with something else when testing):

  ```
  interface IWorld
  {
    IDictionary<string,IStore> Stores { get; set; }
    IDictionary<string,ICityMap> Maps { get; set; }
    ...
  }

  class Consumer
  {
    public Consumer(IWorld world){...}
    public BySomething(string store, string city){...}
  }

  ...

  IWorld myWorld = new HeavenlyWorld();
  ... // adding stores, maps and whatnot

  Consumer c = new Consumer(myWorld);
  ```

  a sub-question: in this case, is IWorld a service locator or not exactly?
- passing a call-back function or delegate (.NET Action in this case):

  ```
  c.BySomething(store, city, new Action(() => {...} ));
  ```

  I added this case because the article [Inversion of Control](http://devmethodologies.blogspot.com/2012/06/inversion-of-control.html) states that every callback is IoC. Is it true?

Comment: your question is if `IWorld` is a service locator?

Comment: That's a question about that one specific case. The most important question is which of those bullet points match to which of the patterns (DI, DIP, IoC, SL).

Answer (score 2):

Everything you listed is a form of Dependency Injection.

1. "Poor Man's" DI
2. DI using an IoC container
3. "Poor Man's" DI again. DI works whether you are using an interface or an abstract class.
4. Method Injection
5. I'm not sure what you're asking here. It sounds like you want to change the instance of IWorld at runtime, which might be a case for Property Injection instead of Constructor Injection. Properties are oft used for optional dependencies or those that can change. Whether you then set that dependency at run-time with a Service Locator or other means is up to you. Another thing to consider is that IWorld might just depend on context, in which case you could do a context-depdendent constructor injection, the details of which are beyond the scope of this question.
6. Not related to DI

Comment: But is the 6th point still a valid case of IoC? I ask this because the article here http://devmethodologies.blogspot.com/2012/06/inversion-of-control.html states that callback functions can be considered IoC. Is it right?

Comment: I see the article's point. Technically it is IoC, but it's not what comes to mind within the context of DI and IoC containers.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you pass a dependency as a constructor/method argument, that's Dependecy Injection. It can be manual, like in most of your examples, or automatic using a DI Container aka IoC Container.

Using a container means the objects using deps are constructed by the container. You could ask the container directly for that service and in that case, there's a static property or method ( think DependecyResolver in asp.net mvc) that exposes that service. In that case you're using the Service Locator pattern. **IWork** in your example is not a locator, it's just a dependency.

To continue with the dependency resolver example, you register all relevant types into a container, the container is build then registered as the dependency resolver. The asp.net mvc framwork then uses the resolver (the Service Locator - SL) to instantiate controllers, views and all the deps these require.

To use the SL pattern is ok as part of a framework, but it's not ok if you're using it in your app to instantiate objects, because it couples the code to the locator. Sometimes is the only solution but 99% you is just an anti-pattern.

Comment: Can we reduce it to minimum and call it DI when we pass arguments of primitive data types (int, string) to some function? After all, this function depends on that data, and might even modify that data (if we pass by ref) giving us some kind of primitive call-back. But does it make it DI and IoC? And is it also dependency inversion principle or not?

Comment: No, DI is not about passing args to a method. It's about supplying the required 'services', dependencies which should be abstractions, not concrete types. IoC is based on abstractions, because the higher level object defines the needed abstraction, while the lower lvl object provides the implementation (unknown to the higher object and thus decoupled). With concrete types, the lower lvl object is in control, while here, the control is reversed.